# WPF databinding ToolTips won't get updated

Tags: wpf, data-binding, tooltip

I need to display some `ToolTip`s and have a `CheckBox` to display it and hide it. I have the databinding but it won't get updated. The bool value seems always true which means that the `ToolTip` won't disappear even when the `CheckBox` is unchecked.

WPF Code

```
<Button Name="btnCancel" Content="Cancel" 
        ToolTipService.IsEnabled="{Binding GeneralDisplayTooltipsForPreferencesAndSearchOptions}"
        ToolTip="Discard Changes On All Tabs and Close Dialog"
        Height="25" Width="80" Margin="0,5,2,5"
        VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="btnCancel_Click"/>
```

---

C#

```
public class General : INotifyPropertyChanged, IPreferencesGeneral
{

    private bool generalDisplayTooltipsForPreferencesAndSearchOptions = false;

    [field: NonSerializedAttribute()]
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate
    {

    };

    public bool GeneralDisplayTooltipsForPreferencesAndSearchOptions
    { 
        get { return generalDisplayTooltipsForPreferencesAndSearchOptions; }
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(generalDisplayTooltipsForPreferencesAndSearchOptions, value))
            {
                generalDisplayTooltipsForPreferencesAndSearchOptions = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("GeneralDisplayTooltipsForPreferencesAndSearchOptions");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you set the event to a delegate? Shouldn't just declaring it be enough? Also, please include the code for the `CheckBox` that is bound to `GeneralDisplayTooltipsForPreferencesAndSearchOptions`.

Comment: @Andy: Some people do that so they don't have to check for `null` before raising the event.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have correct `DataContext`. Also see output if you have any binding errors.

Also, if you want to control `ToolTip` enable state from `CheckBox` (and the check box is in the same context) you may just bind `IsEnabled` to `CheckBox` `IsChecked` (with relative binding)

This code works on my machine, see example:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication11.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="525"
    Height="350">
<Grid>
    <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Top"
              IsChecked="{Binding GeneralDisplayTooltipsForPreferencesAndSearchOptions}"
              Content="Check me!" />
    <Button Name="btnCancel"
            Width="80"
            Height="25"
            Margin="0,5,2,5"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Content="Cancel"
            ToolTip="Discard Changes On All Tabs and Close Dialog"
            ToolTipService.IsEnabled="{Binding GeneralDisplayTooltipsForPreferencesAndSearchOptions}" />
</Grid>
```

And the viewmodel:

```
namespace WpfApplication11
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = new General();
    }


}

public class General : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private bool generalDisplayTooltipsForPreferencesAndSearchOptions = false;

    [field: NonSerializedAttribute()]
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate
    {

    };

    public bool GeneralDisplayTooltipsForPreferencesAndSearchOptions
    {
        get { return generalDisplayTooltipsForPreferencesAndSearchOptions; }
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(generalDisplayTooltipsForPreferencesAndSearchOptions, value))
            {
                generalDisplayTooltipsForPreferencesAndSearchOptions = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("GeneralDisplayTooltipsForPreferencesAndSearchOptions");
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string p)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The checkbox has the data binding also. It is still not working. Now somehow the tooltip disappeared but it won't get back on even I check the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not for the all application you should let the view handle it.
Do something like that:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="checkBoxTooltip" ></CheckBox>
<Button ToolTip="Cancel" ToolTipService.IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=checkBoxTooltip, Path=IsChecked}" />
```